# I'm stuck in the first epoch of a sentiment classifier training process

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to execute a code very similar to this one: https://www.kaggle.com/code/prakharrathi25/sentiment-analysis-using-bert/notebook

The only thing that i've changed is the database and the pre-trained model from BERT. (The code in the link above uses the 'bert-base-cased'pre-trained model while I use the neuralmind/bert-base-portuguese-cased'.

The code runs nicely on google collab until I get to

```
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):

  print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{EPOCHS}')
  print('-' * 10)

  train_acc, train_loss = train_epoch(
    model,
    train_data_loader,    
    loss_fn, 
    optimizer, 
    device, 
    scheduler, 
    len(df_train)
  )

  print(f'Train loss {train_loss} accuracy {train_acc}')

  val_acc, val_loss = eval_model(
    model,
    val_data_loader,
    loss_fn, 
    device, 
    len(df_val)
  )

  print(f'Val   loss {val_loss} accuracy {val_acc}')
  print()

  history['train_acc'].append(train_acc)
  history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)
  history['val_acc'].append(val_acc)
  history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)

  if val_acc > best_accuracy:
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model_state.bin')
    best_accuracy = val_acc
```

In this block, the console doesnt even return the `print(f'Train loss {train_loss} accuracy {train_acc}')` in the for loop.

I suspect the problem is in this part of the definition of the `train_epoch()` function:

```
def train_epoch(
  model, 
  data_loader, 
  loss_fn, 
  optimizer, 
  device, 
  scheduler, 
  n_examples
):
  model = model.train()

  losses = []
  correct_predictions = 0
  
  for d in data_loader:
    input_ids = d["input_ids"].to(device)
    attention_mask = d["attention_mask"].to(device)
    targets = d["targets"].to(device)
```

Because when I tested the same loop, but to just print the `input_ids` variable in spyder, the code would run forever without retuning anything in the console. Weirdly enough, when I tested the same loop in Google Collab, it returned all the `input_ids` in the loop.

Just to mention, my training data set has 17280 rows, and I have set the size of batches to 16.So each one of them has 1080 rows.

Are the info above sufficient enough to get any help on why I cant get past the 1st epoch of the training process? Thanks in advance!

Comment: for fun, I like the sprintf approach. try printing the for loop in the train_epoch, maybe only every other 5 iterations. I suspect data_loader fetches data from somewhere, and feeds it to your method. Give it a try, maybe it's stuck retrieving data from wherever it retrieves it from